# Gradle version does not update Windows 10

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I manually installed Gradle as the given instructions in https://gradle.org/install
to latest v-5.6.2

I have setup the GRADLE_HOME and added the bin location to PATH also. 
But when I run the `gradle --version` it shows me `Gradle 5.2.1`

I uninstalled Android studio also. But still, I can see the same result.

Where can I found the location of old version or how can I remove old version?

Comment: Execute `where gradle` to see which executable is being used. Note that setting environment variables typically requires restarting the terminal in order for the changes to be seen; you may even need to log out and log back in or restart the OS for the changes to take full effect.

Comment: I found out that there is a choco package for gradle has installed. Just moved custom gradle path on top works or me. Thank you.